# Failed to initialize anaconda directories Windows 11

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook, anaconda, anaconda3, jupyter-irkernel

I installed anaconda the latest version of anaconda, anaconda3-2022.05 and i got the error failed to initialize anaconda directories and it is pointing towards anaconda3\lib_nsis.py and i don't know what is the problem and even when using old version of anaconda still get the same error.
Can someone help please